# Is it possible to stop auto direction to another website?

Tags: browser, website

I am accessing a website, but it is automatically redirected to another website in about 2 seconds before I can click the stop button in Firefox. For example, this website www.duda.org

So I wonder if it is possible to stop auto direction?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/388370/in-firebug-how-can-i-stop-a-redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the **Options > Advanced** tab. There is an option under **Accessibility** to notify you when a webpage tries to redirect. The page will then only redirect if you **allow** it to.

[image: screenshot]